# React Error: Invalid hook call - even though syntax seems correct

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I apologize for the redundant post (I realize that questions regarding this issue have been posted multiple times :/  ).

However, I've been through multiple posts and still cannot see what is causing the error.  The syntax that I am using appears to be correct.  I have tried re-writing the export statement, as well as the component itself multiple times, to no avail (everything compiles just fine).  I am simply trying to wrap the site pages in a container using a bootstrap react component.  Any help would be seriously appreciated.  Code is listed below:

Layout component that is causing error:

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

export const Layout = (props) => (
        <Container>
            {props.children}
        </Container>    
)
```

App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { About } from './About';
import { Work } from './Work';
import { Design } from './Design';
import { Contact } from './Contact';
import { FourOFour } from './FourOFour';



class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Layout>
      
        <Router>
          <Switch>

            <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
            <Route path='/about' component={ About } />
            <Route path='/work' component={ Work } />
            <Route path='/design' component={ Design } />
            <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact } />
            <Route component={ FourOFour} />

          </Switch>
        </Router>
      
      </Layout>
    </React.Fragment> 
   )
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else has this issue, check your dependencies in the json package file and make sure bootstrap-react is listed there.  If it is not, it will through this error.  It's easy to overlook or possibly install in the wrong folder and think it's there.